# ShellProcessFailed Error for Backup Manager - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I receive the error

> 'ShellProcessFailed in ShellProcessor.php line 35:'

on creating database backup by using Laravel Backup Manager

Using XAMPP mysql and laravel 5 framework on Windows 10

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file_name' => 'max:30|regex:/^[\w._-]+$/'
    ]);

    try {
        $manager = app()->make(Manager::class);
        $fileName = $request->get('file_name') ?: date('Y-m-d_Hi');

        $manager->makeBackup()->run('mysql', [
                new Destination('local', 'backup/db/' . $fileName)
            ], 'gzip');

        return redirect()->route('backups.index');
    } catch (FileExistsException $e) {
        return redirect()->route('backups.index');
    }
}
```

Actual result(error):

> ShellProcessFailed in ShellProcessor.php line 35: Expected result:
>   Successful backup process

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is an issue with the compressor function for 'gzip' type. Therefore I disabled the gzip compression by setting it to null as displayed on the code.

FROM:

```
$manager->makeBackup()->run('mysql', [
                new Destination('local', 'backup/db/' . $fileName)
            ], 'gzip');
```

TO:

```
$manager->makeBackup()->run('mysql', [
                new Destination('local', 'backup/db/' . $fileName)
            ], 'null');
```

This worked for me as I don't need my files to be compressed.